Why do I get an error about a column my code doesn't address?
I'm using Delphi 12 creating a Multi_Device application. I have an SQLite database with table Profile. I created two forms to see if I could find the problem.
I added a datamodule with an FDConnection and a FDTable where the connection is set to the FDConnection and the table name is set to the table Profile in the database, the FDConnection is set to my database. Everything was working until I debug on Android and found that only the database was transferred, but no table.
I copied the CREATE TABLE SQL directly from DB Browser for SQLite. The table gets created but when I execute FDTable1.Open I get:

I have no column called A.MOBILE and the table it creates I can populate in the DB Browser for SQLite.
procedure TDataModule2.FDConnection1AfterConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin

 if FDConnection1.DataSetCount = 0 then
begin
    FDConnection1.ExecSQL('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Profile" (   "Firstname" TEXT NOT NULL,"Lastname"    TEXT NOT NULL, " Street1 " TEXT NOT NULL, " Street2 " TEXT, " City " TEXT NOT NULL, " Apartment " TEXT, " Building " TEXT, " State " TEXT NOT NULL, " Zip " TEXT NOT NULL, " Phone " TEXT," Email " TEXT, " Mobile " TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, " Refby " TEXT, " Starch " TEXT, " RecEmail " INTEGER DEFAULT 1," RecSMS " INTEGER DEFAULT 1, " Verified " INTEGER DEFAULT 0," RefCode " TEXT, " CustomerID " INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(" Mobile "))');
    FDTable1.Open;
    FDTable1.Append;
end
else
begin
     FDTable1.Open;
end;

end;

procedure TDataModule2.FDConnection1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
var
dbPath: String;
begin
dbPath := 'C:\ComcaMobileDelphi\database\ComcaMApp.db';

{$IF DEFINED(IOS) or DEFINED(ANDROID)}

dbPath := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'ComcaMApp.db';

{$ENDIF}

FDConnection1.Params.Values['Database'] := dbPath;

end;


Get rid of ALL of those double quotes.  You are creating a column called "space Mobile space" (along with the others), and that's just going to confuse things.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. It's even worse that you did so when there is a clear Copy button on the error dialog that generates a textual representation of the error for you to paste, yet you failed to use it. Also, you do not put double quotes around column names unless they contain an embedded space, and even then it's better to use square brackets instead if your DBMS allows them. If you DO use double quotes, do not leave spaces around the column name at all - it should be "CITY", not " CITY ".

I made a new table with no NOT NULL and no UNIQUE and no Index I no longer get the error.
I still don't know why I got the error.
Sorry, my old Delphi didn't have the copy button for errors.
Since I copied the sql string directly from the SQLite DB Browser application and it worked there, I didn't think it mattered. I will try again without spaces, but I can not see how you would make the Sql string without double quotes. When I create SQLite strings in Android, to create tables, they have double quotes as well.
The problem was that I had a index in the database, but I didn't create it, the index name was Mobile.
